# Set of all subset is a sigma algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In the book Measure, Integration and Real Analysis (Axler, 2020), the author claims that:

> Suppose $X$ is a set. Then the set of all subsets of $X$ is a $\sigma-$ algebra on $X$

Then he defines the *measurable set*:

> A measurable space is an ordered pair $(X,S)$ where $X$ is a set and $S$ is a $\sigma -$ algebra on $X$.
> An element of $S$ is called an $S$ measurable set (or just a *measurable set* if $S$ is clear from the context.

I have a question concerning the measurablity of every subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
As we know, not every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable ($i.e$ it does not belong to any $\sigma -$ algebra. So the set of all subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can't be a $\sigma -$ algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ which contradicts the claim of the author.

Could you please explain me what does the author mean ? Or is there any misunderstanding in my mind when reading the book ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set   $\mathcal{P}(X)$ of all subsets of $X$ is a sigma algebra because it satisfies the axioms for that kind of structure. That is independent of any discussion of measures.

The definition of a measure space is a pair $(X,S)$ where $S$ is some subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ that happens to be a sigma algebra. It may or may not be all of $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

When you set out to define Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ you soon discover that you can't get all the properties you want if you try to assign a "length" to every subset of $\mathbb{R}$. So you restrict the definition of "length" to a subalgebra $S$ of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ and call those the measurable sets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in the definition of the author, if a set belongs to a $\sigma - $ algebra then it is called "measurable", so by this reason, every subset of R must be called "measurable", right ? I still can't get the idea. Could you please give me further explanation ?

Comment: "Measurable" does not mean "belongs to a sigma algebra". When you have a particular measure space in mind - a particular pair $(X,S)$ - then "measurable" means "belongs to [that particular] $S$". There is no notion of measurable independent of a particular sigma algebra. To say that not every subset of the reals is measurable means that there are subsets that don't belong to the particular sigma algebra on which Lebesgue measure is defined.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand that every subset of R can be considered "measurable" (i.e. belong to the $\sigma-$ algebra P(S)), but just with respect to *some* measure other than Lebesgue measure. Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, that's about right, though not particularly useful.  I'd say every set is measurable "with respect to some sigma algebra" rather than "with respect to some measure".

Comment: Just a further curious question please. Can we define two different measures on the same $\sigma$ algebra ?

Comment: Certainly. If $f$ is any  Lebesgue integrable function you can define the measure $\mu$ by setting  $\mu(A)$ to be the Lebesgue integral of $f$ on $A$.

Comment: Yes, so I think saying "the set is measurable with respect to a sigma algebra" would not give the accurate meaning. Because, for the same sigma algebra, a set can be measurable if we use *some* measure and not-measurable if we use *some other* measure ? (like in the case of Lebesgue measure on P(R))

Comment: No. But we are discussing a small point with no mathematical significance. Just move on to the substance of measure theory.

Answer (score 4):

The assertion “not every subset of $\Bbb R$ is measurable” is valid for the Lebesgue measure. Anyway, here Axler is talking about $\sigma$-algebras, not about measures. And, yes, $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ *is* a $\sigma$-algebra. And, on this $\sigma$-algebra you can define the measure $m(X)=\#X$; with respect to this measure, $\Bbb R$ *is* measurable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. So, as I understood from your answer, every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is indeed measurable with respect to *some* (i.e. there exists such a measure) measure function other than Lebesgue measure ? So why we bother with the non-measurability of subset of R with respect to Lebesgue measure ? Thank you.

Comment: Because the Lebesgue measure is, by far, the most used measure in Real Analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. As you said, we can define a function that can measure every subset of R (which, as i think, is a very nice and strong property), so why don't we use this kind of measure ? (because, yes, it can measure *everything* in R)

Comment: Yes, but don't you thank that a measure $m$ such that, for each interval $[a,b]$, $m([a,b])=b-a$ is much more natural? With respect to the measure that I mentioned, the measure of each such interval is $\infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!